# Sending a post request in cURL to get cookie works on one web hosting but not the other

Tags: php, curl, post, cookies, http-headers

so I have hostgator to host `domain.com` and hostinger to host `test.com`. In those websites I have the exact same script running. What the script does is, it logs into an external website `example.com`, grabs the login cookie and stores it. This cookie works for months! Then goes to `example.com/need-to-be-logged-in-to-view-this-page` and gets its contents.

However, I face an issue. I have the exact same code on both hosting companies. It works perfectly on hostgator. However, on hostinger, it logs in, grabs the cookie, but the cookie only works that one time when it logs in.

So then I generated the cookie on hostgator and copied that cookie over to hostinger and it worked perfectly. **So I am wondering, is there some sort of setting in cURL or something default that hostgator may have enabled and hostinger may not which makes the cookie generated on hostinger only last for that one second when it logged in.**

```
function get_login_cookie($ch, $headerLine) {
    if (strncmp($headerLine, "set-cookie: coolCookie=", 20) == 0) {
        $endPos = strpos($headerLine, ";");
        $coolCookie = substr($headerLine, 20, ($endPos - 20));
        file_put_contents("cookie.txt", $coolCookie);
    }
    return strlen($headerLine);
}

function login($username, $password) {
    $fields = [
        "username"      => $username,
        "password"      => $password
    ];
    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

    $ch = curl_init("https://example.com/login");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "get_login_cookie");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    curl_exec($ch);
}
```

---

So I tried printing `$headerLiner` from the `get_login_cookie()` function. They are pretty different. How does Hostinger and hostgator not have the same response with the exact same code.

On hostgator when I print out `$headerLiner`

```
HTTP/2 201 
server: nginx/1.15.6
date: Sun, 21 Jul 2019 23:59:04 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 479
set-cookie: coolCookie=THIS_IS_THE_COOKIE; Domain=.example.com; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 28-Jul-19 23:59:04 UTC; HttpOnly
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
pragma: no-cache
vary: Accept,Cookie,Authorization,X-EXAMPLE-Sauce
location: https://api.example.com/login/8gybiuf8gybundfguino
p3p: CP='TST'
set-cookie: browser_session=browser_gfdhfdguy46ytyrty/oMnIg; Domain=.example.com; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 21-Jul-69 23:59:04 UTC; HttpOnly
set-cookie: window_session=window_45gh56yjhttrghf4; Domain=.example.com; Path=/; HttpOnly
set-cookie: coolCookie=THIS_IS_THE_COOKIE; Domain=.example.com; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 28-Jul-19 23:59:04 UTC; HttpOnly
x-example-rnd: p3456ythth4567yt
```

When I print `$headerLine` on hostinger. Hostinger's response is missing `HTTP/2 201`, `browser session`, `window session` etc

```
server: nginx/1.15.6
date: Sun, 21 Jul 2019 23:46:41 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 180
set-cookie: coolCookie=THIS_IS_THE_COOKIE; expires=Sun, 28-Jul-2019 23:46:41 GMT; Max-Age=604800; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
pragma: no-cache
set-cookie: coolCookie=THIS_IS_THE_COOKIE; expires=Sun, 28-Jul-2019 23:46:41 GMT; Max-Age=604800; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly
vary: Accept,Cookie,Authorization,X-EXAMPLE-Sauce
x-example-rnd: OD4wQjIDT5ug0C
```

Comment: It's possible that it's due to curl/php versions. Can you set the post URL to a requestbin and post the result here? https://requestbin.com/

Comment: @atymic I checked the curl version. Hostgator has 7.19.x and Hostinger has 7.62.0. Hostinger has a new version, so shouldn;t the script work on hostinger too?

Comment: Can you post the requestbin of a request from each server? That way we can check what is different about the requests sent.

Comment: @atymic not really sure how to use it

Comment: Update the URL your code is calling to `https://en2ntkal5pml6.x.pipedream.net` (the requestbin) and then trigger your code on both servers.

Comment: You can then view the requests that were sent here: https://requestbin.com/r/en2ntkal5pml6

Comment: @atymic I managed to make a request bin myself and send it. Both have the same headers same same body

Comment: @atymic https://requestbin.com/r/eny6kyz824868/1OLTzypyP0Ad8CE7sj5XHdmzJRM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196790/discussion-between-atymic-and-tim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the API was returning a `400` error code. This was probably due to the differences in the curl user agent between the servers (resulting in the API blocking the request).

```php
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36']
```